# Joystick Program Not Running (no values printed)

Tags: c, runtime-error, printf, joystick

Ok so I'm back, my code now compiles successfully, it just does nothing when I run it, not even printing "Joystick Open Successful". I can't see any obvious reasons for this, any ideas?

```
Again excuse my commenting:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/joystick.h>             /* lots of included headers because */ 
                                            /*  I wasn't sure which I needed!   */

#define JS_EVENT_AXIS           0x02            /* joystick moved */


int open_joystick(int fd) {                 /* function to open the     joystick */

    fd = open ("/dev/js0", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);      /* setting fd to open the joystick  */
         if (fd >= 0) {                                  /* in non blocking mode            */
             printf("Open Joystick Successful");
                                 }                  
return fd;                          /* functions like to return something */
}

void read_joystick_thrust_axis(int fd, struct js_event js) {    /* another function, including the integer fd,  */
                                /* the structure js 

while (read (fd, &js, sizeof(js)) > 0) {            /* while there is a joystick event to read */
    if (js.type == JS_EVENT_AXIS && js.number == 1){    /* and if that event is an axis event */
                                            /* and if that event is on the right axis */
            printf ("Thrust Reading: %8hd\n", js.value);    /* print the values of it */
        }
    }

int main() {
    int fd;
    struct js_event js;
    fd = open_joystick(fd);
    while (1) {
        read_joystick_thrust_axis(fd, js);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it does not print your successful message, maybe it is not successful. Try checking the `errno` or using `perror()` to check whether it is actually failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lines are wrong:

```
if (fd < 0) {
    printf("Open Joystick Successful");
```

`open` returns `-1` when it fails, or something `>=0` if it succeeds, so you have the logic wrong.

Probably your `open()` is failing because you lack permissions to open this device. Or maybe it does not exist... (`/dev/input/js0`?). Just check `errno` to be sure:

```
if (fd < 0)
    perror("/dev/js0");
```